# Using QPushbutton to pass variables into a second script and execute it

Tags: python, qprocess, qpushbutton

I'm trying to use the input values of a PyQt5 gui to run a second python script.
The problem that I'm guetting is: cannot import name 'outer_radius' from 'GeneratorApp' (E:\Blank generator\GeneratorApp.py)

I'm assuming it is because the variables are not global, I found that I can use "Qprocess()" but I have no idea how this might work since I'm a complete beginner when it comes to programming.
My main code is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocessCaller


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #Main window setup
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 371)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        #Generate button setup
        self.GenerateBlanks = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.GenerateBlanks.setObjectName("GenerateBlanks")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.GenerateBlanks, 12, 0, 1, 1)
        self.GenerateBlanks.clicked.connect(self.generate)
        #Qline edit setup
        self.MinUcSize = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.MinUcSize.setObjectName("MinUcSize")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.MinUcSize, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.MaterialDensity = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.MaterialDensity.setObjectName("MaterialDensity")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.MaterialDensity, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.BoreRadius = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.BoreRadius.setObjectName("BoreRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.BoreRadius, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.FileDirectory = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.FileDirectory.setObjectName("FileDirectory")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.FileDirectory, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.OuterRadius = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.OuterRadius.setObjectName("OuterRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.OuterRadius, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.MaxUcSize = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.MaxUcSize.setObjectName("MaxUcSize")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.MaxUcSize, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.BlankWidth = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.BlankWidth.setObjectName("BlankWidth")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.BlankWidth, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.InnerRadius = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.InnerRadius.setObjectName("InnerRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.InnerRadius, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.NumberofGenerations = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.NumberofGenerations.setObjectName("NumberofGenerations")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.NumberofGenerations, 11, 1, 1, 1)


        #Horizental sliders setup
        self.RowSpacingFactor = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.RowSpacingFactor.setMinimum(1)
        self.RowSpacingFactor.setMaximum(10)
        self.RowSpacingFactor.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.RowSpacingFactor.setObjectName("RowSpacingFactor")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.RowSpacingFactor, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.ElementSpacingFactor = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.ElementSpacingFactor.setMinimum(1)
        self.ElementSpacingFactor.setMaximum(10)
        self.ElementSpacingFactor.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        #Labels setup
        self.fileDirectory = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.fileDirectory.setObjectName("fileDirectory")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.fileDirectory, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.blankWidth = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.blankWidth.setObjectName("blankWidth")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.blankWidth, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.boreRadius = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.boreRadius.setObjectName("boreRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.boreRadius, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.blankOuterRadius = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.blankOuterRadius.setObjectName("blankOuterRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.blankOuterRadius, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.maximumUnitCellSize = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.maximumUnitCellSize.setObjectName("maximumUnitCellSize")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.maximumUnitCellSize, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rowSpacingFactor = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rowSpacingFactor.setObjectName("rowSpacingFactor")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rowSpacingFactor, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.blankInnerRadius = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.blankInnerRadius.setObjectName("blankInnerRadius")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.blankInnerRadius, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.minimumUnitCellSize = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.minimumUnitCellSize.setObjectName("minimumUnitCellSize")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.minimumUnitCellSize, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ElementSpacingFactor.setObjectName("ElementSpacingFactor")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ElementSpacingFactor, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.materialDensity = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.materialDensity.setObjectName("materialDensity")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.materialDensity, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.numberofGenerations = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.numberofGenerations.setObjectName("numberofGenerations")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.numberofGenerations, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.patternControlParameters = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.patternControlParameters.setFont(font)
        self.patternControlParameters.setObjectName("patternControlParameters")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.patternControlParameters, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.GenerateBlanks.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate blanks"))
        self.MinUcSize.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.MaterialDensity.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7.86e-3"))
        self.BoreRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "15.00"))
        self.FileDirectory.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E:/FreeCAD macro/Gear generator"))
        self.OuterRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "50.00"))
        self.fileDirectory.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "File directory:"))
        self.blankWidth.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blank width:"))
        self.BlankWidth.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "20.00"))
        self.boreRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bore radius:"))
        self.MaxUcSize.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.blankOuterRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blank outer radius:"))
        self.InnerRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10.00"))
        self.NumberofGenerations.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.maximumUnitCellSize.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Maximum unit cell size:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Element spacing factor:"))
        self.rowSpacingFactor.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row spacing factor:"))
        self.blankInnerRadius.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blank inner radius:"))
        self.minimumUnitCellSize.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Minimum unit cell size:"))
        self.materialDensity.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Material density:"))
        self.numberofGenerations.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number of generations:"))
        self.patternControlParameters.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pattern control parameters:"))


    def generate(self):
        file_directory = str(self.FileDirectory.text())
        outer_radius = float(self.OuterRadius.text())
        inner_radius = float(self.InnerRadius.text())
        bore_radius = float(self.BoreRadius.text())
        blank_width = float(self.BlankWidth.text())
        material_density = float(self.MaterialDensity.text())
        min_uc_size = int(self.MinUcSize.text())
        max_uc_size = int(self.MaxUcSize.text())
        row_spacing_factor = int(self.RowSpacingFactor.value())/10
        element_spacing_factor = int(self.ElementSpacingFactor.value())/10
        iterations = int(self.NumberofGenerations.text())



        ## calling the file(path)       
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            c = subprocessCaller.CallPy("E:\Blank generator\guest.py")
            c.call_python_file()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the "subProcessCaller" code I'm using to execute the "guest.py" file is:

```
from subprocess import call

class CallPy:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def call_python_file(self):
        call(["Python", "{}". format(self.path)])
```

Finally, the process I wan to execute by clicking on the QpushButto is a simple sommation of 2 variables imported from the main process (inputs coming from the gui):

```
from GeneratorApp import outer_radius, inner_radius
print(f"{outer_radius + inner_radius}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting import errors because outer_radius is out of scope. The way outer_radius is declared, it's a local variable and is only alive in the `generate` method.

Some people advocate separating the program logic from the GUI. I don't know if that's what you're trying to do here. I've never bothered to do that.

If it was me, I would make outer_radius class level variables, e.g.

```
self.outer_radius = outer_radius = float(self.OuterRadius.text()) # instead of outer_radius = ...
```

In **init** method, add your button

```
self.mybutton = QPushButton('Sum', parent = self.centralwidget, objectName = 'mybutton')
self.mybutton.clicked.connect(on_mybutton_clicked)
```

Then make a new method for Ui_MainWindow

```
def on_mybutton_clicked(self):
    print(self.outer_radius + self.inner_radius)
```